# blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: laravel, ionic, typescript

estoy queriendo consumir una api que hice en Laravel desde ionic.. Simplemente es una prueba pues estoy empezando en ionic.
Para consumir la api cree un servicio

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EncuestasService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient ) { }

  getTiendas() {
    return this.http.get(`http://192.168.1.110:8000/api/tiendas`);
  }
}
```

Luego voy al page.ts de mi pagina y lo llamo

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EncuestasService } from '../../services/encuestas.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page implements OnInit {
    constructor(private tiendasService: EncuestasService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.tiendasService.getTiendas()
        .subscribe(respuesta => {
            console.log(respuesta);
        });
    }
}
```

y luego me bloquea el navegador la peticion con este error en consola
**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.1.110:8000/api/tiendas' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

El codigo se que funciona porque probe consumir otra api y funciona

```
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
```

Asi que pienso que es un problema de servidor o es por mi localhost.. La verdad no entiendo bien el problema..
Mi controlador

```
public function index()
    {
        //
        $users = User::where('activo', '=', '1')->get();
        return ['users' => $users];
    }
```

mi api.php

```
Route::resource('/tiendas', 'UsuariosController');
```

Comment: Debes agregar el encabezado en el lado Servidor. Prueba: `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8100");`, para dar acceso sólo a tu webpack local. Puedes leer un poco sobre el tema en [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Server-Side_Access_Control). Saludos

Comment: Disculpa,como agrego el encabezado?

Comment: Lo agregas en tu controlador. Aunque @abrahamhs te dio una solución global. Sin embargo si deseas tener control sobre CORS en cada app, lo haces en tu código PHP antes de enviar los datos al cliente. Como ya dije, lo haces en tu controlador.

Comment: Entonces lo agrego dentro de mi metodo y nada mas?

Comment: Agregue `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8100"); a mi index.php`  y ya funciona

Comment: Claro, suponiendo que tu controlador es `UsuariosController`, las primeras lineas del mismo podrían ser: `<?php (salto de linea) header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8100"); (salto de linea) header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");`, además si deseas poner un [header preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Preflight_peticion), puedes agregar `header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');`

Comment: Excelente. Un gusto ayudarte

Comment: Gracias por el dato

Answer (score 1):

Existe una manera muy facil en Ionic de poder consumir apis, como entenderas tu aplicación no esta en el mismo host que tus servicios y existe una configuración dentro del archivo `ionic.config.json`

```
"proxies": [
    {
       "path": "/api_tiendas",
       "proxyUrl": "http://192.168.1.110:8000/api/"
    }
 ],
```

Entonces, ahora cada llamado que hagas a la api debe ser asi:

```
return this.http.get('/api_tiendas/tiendas');
```

Por qué te recomiendo esta forma? Porque la aplicación desde los dispositivos no obtendras estos errores de cors, sin embargo, para pruebas con `ionic serve` te evitas configurar tu servidor para que acepte llamadas desde cualquier fuente.

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar el error **blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin** hay que editar el archivo **httpd.conf** de apache y agregar si estamos en apache wampp

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

en xampp pudiera ser

```
 <IfModule mod_headers.so>
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

o incluir ambos y reiniciar el servidor

Comment: agregue a mi apache2.conf la linea de codigo que me pasaste pero el error persiste

Comment: En node.js con angular a mi me salia ese error y así lo elimine, acabo de revisar mi xampp y así esta configurado. Tal vez lo aplicaste EN EL OTRO servidor o tal vez estas haciendo otra cosa mal, revisa tus rutas.

Comment: De hecho es mas o menos lo mismo que te recomienda @Mauricio Contreras solo que eso aplica solo a ese script.

Comment: Use la solucion de mauricio y agregue `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8100");` a mi index.php

Comment: No modifiques el servidor para aceptar llamados libres, puede causarte problemas de seguridad