# Erro al obtener json de mi api en laravel local con react

Tags: php, laravel, reactjs

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/notas' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

el end-point de la api es http://localhost:8000/notas y solicito con react desde http://localhost:3000

Comment: Tendrías que hacer alguna pregunta... parece solo un informe  'telegráfico' de un error. Lee [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y luego [editala](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/313714/edit) de manera que sepamos cuál es la pregunta concretamente.

Comment: posible duplicado de [blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/258153/blocked-by-cors-policy-no-access-control-allow-origin) y [Falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: Gracias, voy a intentar con este

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que activar en php la cabecera Access-Controll-Allow-Origin para que le permita solicitar datos a la url http://localhost:8000 eso se hace poniendo la linea de codigo

en laravel usando composer debes hacer

```
composer require spatie/laravel-cors
```

y luego en el archivo **app/Http/Kernel.php** agregar la clase *cors* como middleware

```
protected $middleware = [
    ...
    \Spatie\Cors\Cors::class
];
```

Comment: Gracias Victor, intente esto pero sigue bloqueando la solicitud...